# VBA -Nested For Loop Alternative or Ignore a Value if Satisfied Once

Tags: vba

the following code works but I believe there must be a better way of doing it. I would love to hear alternate strategies.

The purpose of my code is to find out if any Letter (Z, A,B,C) has the value 1 in their corresponding cell beside it. And if the letter does I want to copy all corresponding values for that letter.

Column1___Column 2

Z_________0

Z_________1

C_________1

A_________0

C_________1

B_________0

Result:

Z_________0

Z_________1

C_________1

C_________1

I marked rows that contained a letter that has already satisfied the criteria of containing a "1"  with the word "RHO". This was my quick fix to prevent it from copying values twice ( i.e. the C rows above were copied twice cause there are two occurrences of 1)

```
  Sub Testzone()
  Dim rng As range
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim catid
  Dim cell
  Dim col1

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
For Each cell In wb.Sheets(1).range("B1", Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

If cell.Value = 1 Then
     catid = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

       For Each col1 In wb.Sheets(1).range("A1:A10")
           If col1 = catid And col1.Offset(0, 2) <> "RHO" Then
                wb.Sheets(1).Rows(col1.Row).Copy wb.Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                col1.Offset(0, 2).Value = "RHO"
            End If
        Next col1
End If
 Next cell

 End Sub
```

Comment: Are you looking for copying only the unique values in each column?

Comment: I use this to store unique values to an array that is then loaded onto a combobox list. A little adjusting and this should work for you.  `Dim v, e
With Sheets("CTK1INV").Range("Table17[CTK]")
    v = .Value
End With
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .comparemode = 1
    For Each e In v
        If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
    Next
    If .Count Then Me.ComboBox_CTK.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With` (Cant seem to get the formating correct.)